# How to calculate input current of dual polarity output voltage dc-dc converter

Tags: power, dc-dc-converter, efficiency

I am using one of the 10W dual polarity output dc-dc converter. My output specifications are +15V, 50mA and -15V, 50mA. My supply voltage is also 15V. I want to calculate input current. Can anyone help me in this how can i get it?

Comment: Going to need more information, like the model number and a link to the datasheet. At minimum need an efficency

Comment: (50mA+50mA)/effi. Lets assume efficiency is 50%=0.5, so 100mA/0.5 = 200mA input.

Answer (score 0):

Your output power  draw is only 1.5 watts .This is 15% of the 10 watt rating .The part load          efficiency will probably be lower than the full load figure .The input current will   clearly be more than 100mA ,how much more depends on the efficiency specs which you should find .If your DC/Dc was 66% efficient then expect 150mA .